# Xcode sqlite3 seems that nothing works correctly

Tags: xcode, sqlite

i working with newest Xcode and sqlite3 for 4 days now and im kinda getting crazy with it because i just get creepy behavior.

I do this:

```
NSString *selectWPIDQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT ID FROM WORKOUTPLANS WHERE NAME = '%s';", [[aWorkoutPlan name] UTF8String]];
//NSLog(@"%@", [aWorkoutPlan name]);
const char *select_wp_id_query = [selectWPIDQuery UTF8String];

if(sqlite3_open([dbPathString UTF8String], &workoutPlansDB) == SQLITE_OK) {

    int index = sqlite3_exec(workoutPlansDB, select_wp_id_query, NULL, NULL, &error);
    NSLog(@"Der Index %d", index);
}
```

The Index here is 0 but 0 doesnt exist. if i execute this query with the firefox plugin sqlite manager (exactly the same query) it delivers me the index 1 and the index 1 is correkt.

Why the hell sqlite3 in xcode gives me a 0??? Thats not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `sqlite3_exec` incorrectly. It returns a result code, not an index. The result code 0 is `SQLITE_OK`, whereas result code 1 is `SQLITE_ERROR`.

See the [`sqlite3_exec` documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html). You must either provide a callback to get the query results, or use the general purpose `sqlite3_prepare_v2()`, `sqlite3_step()`, and `sqlite3_finalize()` API.